# how to remove the active icon background color (the purple tint here)? react bottom tab navigation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, native, react-navigation-bottom-tab

[bottom bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKUcu.png)[bottom bar here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yroKN.png)[code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIlg4.png)

```
     "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.11",
     "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.2",
```

tried tabBarOptions,activeTintColor.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75306871/edit) to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 1):

Delete "activeBackgroundColor". if there is no code, add "activeBackgroundColor:'transparent'"

Comment: nope not working

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
import { useTheme } from 'react-native-paper';

const theme = useTheme();
theme.colors.secondaryContainer = "transparent"
```

https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/3554